# ARToolkit Multiple Mandatory Markers

Tags: ios, markers, artoolkit

I studied the `multimarker` documentation of `ARToolKit for iOS` and i have some troubles in **achieving** some sort of QR-Code.

I want, **for example:**

A set of 6 markers positioned differently on a picture, and when and only when ALL of them are present, some sort of video is displayed in the origin of them( i want to use some sort of CORNER Markers like QR-Code system ).

How to do this ? From what i've seen, on multimarkers, if 1 is present out of 6 for example, the object is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

From looking into the ARToolKit code you can see that a MultiMarker is internally handled as one single Marker consisting of several Pattern:

https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/blob/master/lib/SRC/ARWrapper/ARMarker.cpp#L344

https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/blob/master/lib/SRC/ARWrapper/ARMarkerMulti.cpp#L75

That is why ARToolKit will always return true whenever one of the markers configured in the multi-marker configuration is visible.

Taking that into account ‘Multi-Markers’ are not the way to go for the target you would like to reach.

What you can do, however, is to configure each marker separately and add them as ‘Single-Marker’. Then you can query if all of these ‘Single-Markers’ are visible.

If so you can calculate the origin of all these ‘Single-Markers’ and render your object there.

You can get an idea on how to configure several ‘Single-Markers’ if you take a look here:

http://augmentmy.world/moving-cars-augmented-reality

Also take that example here on how to set to markers into the same coordinate system (and calculate the distance between them) you can use that as a starting point for calculating the origin between several markers:

https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/AndroidStudioProjects/ARMarkerDistanceProj

I know that these are not iOS examples but I have only done Android so far. Also, the ARWrapper interface should be the same on Android and iOS, meaning to say there should not be much difference between these two.

I hope that helps